# Aggregation of a single data type on a joined table

Tags: sql, join, aggregate

I have a manual report causing 2-3 hours of manual labor weekly for aggregation.

the "a" table gives me the length I want to sum and the "b" table join brings in the name of the activity I need to aggregate.  The issue is that the query does not completely aggregate the value I wish.  The output I am looking for is the a.dtlExcode_ and b.print_name_ with the total sum for the dates selected by a.dtlExcode_.

Can anyone provide some pointers?  I am fairly new to writing queries but am determined to eliminate manual work from canned reports by using the database.

```
select sum(a.dtlLength_) as Total_Minutes, 
a.dtlExcode_,
b.print_name_
from V_SCHEDULE a
left join V_EXCEPT b on a.dtlExcode_ = b.code_
where sched_date_ is between '2021-07-12' and '2021-07-18'
Group by 
  a.sched_date_, 
  a.dtlLength_, 
  a.dtlExcode_, 
  b.print_name_
```

Comment: Your `group by` looks a little suspicous having `sched_date` and `dtlength`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few small errors in the logic.  Here are the adjustments:

```
select sum(a.dtlLength_) as Total_Minutes
     , a.dtlExcode_
     , b.print_name_
  from      V_SCHEDULE a
  left join V_EXCEPT   b
    on a.dtlExcode_ = b.code_
 where sched_date_ between '2021-07-12' and '2021-07-18'
 Group by a.sched_date_, a.dtlExcode_, b.print_name_
;
```

You had included `a.dtlLength_` in the GROUP BY terms, leading to groups for each separate `a.dtlLength_` value.  That was the main problem.

The other `GROUP BY` terms could be fine, depending on your requirement.

If you want each date separately in the result, that's fine.  If not, remove the date term from the `GROUP BY` clause, like so:

```
select sum(a.dtlLength_) as Total_Minutes
     , a.dtlExcode_
     , b.print_name_
  from      V_SCHEDULE a
  left join V_EXCEPT   b
    on a.dtlExcode_ = b.code_
 where sched_date_ between '2021-07-12' and '2021-07-18'
 Group by a.dtlExcode_, b.print_name_
;
```

Comment: Jon!!!!!!!!!  Thank you so much, your explanation is very helpful and the output is what I needed.  Now we now longer need to aggregate in our report since the query does it for us!!!!!

Comment: @ShannonG You're welcome.  If the answer is acceptable, don't forget to "accept" it.  See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer